# Ruby on Rails 6, scrollable table jumping to perceived button location on click, need to prevent this

Tags: javascript, button, ruby-on-rails-6

I am building a webapp on ruby on rails 6 and have a table with buttons inside that is generated with a loop. I wanted this table to itself be scrollable and was able to make that happen, however, the page still generates long enough as if it thinks the table is not scrollable and at a fixed height. This is not the main problem however, the main problem is that when I click a button that is below row 18 in the table, the page jumps to that buttons perceived location as if the table wasnt scrollable, then you have to scroll up past empty page to get back to the table. How can I disable this without removing my buttons functionality?

Here is the code for my table, can provide more if needed.

```ERB
<div class="col-sm">
<div class="table-responsive" style="max-height: 1000px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
  <table class="table table-sm table-striped ml-4" style="max-width: 25rem;">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Left</th>
        <th>Right</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <!-- Loop for table of numbers and creation of all buttons, only loops 54 times and creates table for buttons-->
      <% 54.times do |i| %>
        <% nums = [
          [[1,3],[4,9]],
          [[8],[6]],
          [[3],[9]],
          [[6,1,3],[5,10,2]],
          [[5,9,4],[6,8,1]],
          [[2,8],[10,3]],
          [[3],[1]],
          [[2,6,1],[5,10,4]],
          [[9,4,1],[6,3,10]],
          [[4],[1]],
          [[3,5],[2,8]],
          [[1,3],[6,5]],
          [[8,10,6],[3,2,1]],
          [[6,1],[5,10]],
          [[9],[6]],
          [[1,9,4],[3,2,5]],
          [[9,4],[6,3]],
          [[6,9,8],[4,5,10]],
          [[8,3],[10,4]],
          [[9,4,6],[3,2,5]],
          [[8],[4]],
          [[9,1],[10,2]],
          [[5,9],[8,10]],
          [[1,5,8],[10,9,6]],
          [[4],[9]],
          [[9],[2]],
          [[9],[5]],
          [[8,2,1],[5,10,9]],
          [[2,1],[6,3]],
          [[4],[8]],
          [[6],[2]],
          [[2,5],[8,3]],
          [[1,3,8],[4,9,5]],
          [[10,2],[1,9]],
          [[9],[10]],
          [[3,1,9],[6,5,10]],
          [[10],[8]],
          [[5,2],[10,3]],
          [[6,8,2],[10,1,4]],
          [[9],[3]],
          [[3,5],[4,10]],
          [[10,6,8],[3,4,9]],
          [[5],[3]],
          [[1,9,3],[2,6,5]],
          [[6,8],[10,1]],
          [[6],[9]],
          [[1],[4]],
          [[10,2],[5,1]],
          [[10,3,6],[9,8,2]],
          [[8,1,5],[6,9,2]],
          [[5,2],[4,6]],
          [[8],[1]],
          [[3,4],[9,8]],
          [[2,10,1],[3,9,6]]
          ] %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= i + 1 %></td>

          <td>
            <div class="btn-group-toggle" data="buttons">
              <% group_size = nums[i][0].length %>
              <% nums[i][0].each_with_index do |num, index| %>
                <% button_class = "column1Group#{group_size}-button" %>
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary <%= button_class %>">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="column1[<%= i %>][]" value="<%= num %>">
                  <%= num %>
                </label>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </td>

          <td>
            <div class="btn-group-toggle" data="buttons">
              <% group_size = nums[i][1].length %>
              <% nums[i][1].each_with_index do |num, index| %>
                <% button_class = "column2Group#{group_size}-button" %>
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary <%= button_class %>">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="column2[<%= i %>][]" value="<%= num %>">
                  <%= num %>
                </label>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have tried e.stopPropagation(); and e.preventDefault(); on the buttons in javascript scripts, but those did not work for different reasons. prevent default stops all button functionality and stop propagation did not fix the issue at all.